# Okta custom integration invalid credentials on /token endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

I'm trying to create an integration with Okta for our customers.
I've created a custom integration in Okta with type of OIDC as a Web Application. I've configured the callback url and in general settings i've checked the Authorization Code and the Refresh token.

The authorization_url (which is created in our system and is exposed through our portal) seems like this:

```
https://{{my_instance}}/oauth2/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={public_key}}&redirect_uri={{my_configured_redirect_uri}}&scope=okta.groups.manage+okta.groups.read+okta.users.manage+okta.users.read+okta.users.read.self&state={{state}}
```

which seems ok to me.

The redirect uri posts back the authorization code, which im trying to exchange for an access_token.
The /token endpoint returns an

```
invalid_client: Client authentication failed. Either the client or the client credentials are invalid.
```

I expect the oauth2 flow and the /token endpoint to work without problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you authenticate your call to /token? I mean are you passing a header/body according to the documentation?

Comment: I do not authenticate the /token endpoint. The flow i am using is "authorization_code" so i just pass a code query parameter to exchange it for an access token. The codebase supports already multiple oauth2 flows at this moment but just Okta integration isn't working.

Comment: are you sure in Okta your application does not require authentication. You said you created it as Web app which by default produce client_id/client_secret. These parameters participate in a call to /token

Comment: I am going to give it a try and i ll let you know! thanks!

Comment: In the end, their /token endpoint requires BasicAuth which means in my request i had to pass the client_id & client_secret as username and password.
We had this integration in my company for like 2 years now, but i ugess Okta changed something from their side?
Thank's again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ιn the end, their /token endpoint requires BasicAuth which means in my request i had to pass the client_id & client_secret as username and password. We had this integration in my company for like 2 years now, but i ugess Okta changed something from their side? No idea.
Thank's again!!